# Show total sum for all rows based on rank

Tags: sql

How I can show the sum of values based on rank.

Suppose if tenure is 1W then i need should show the last 3 values sum to all the rows and if tenure is 3M then last 5 days and if tenure is 6M then last 10 days.

Below query for your reference and attached screenshot for the same. Need to fix the result at Calculation column.

```
SELECT created_date, contributor, Tenor, hist_date, hist_rate,
       SUM(case when tenor in ('O/N','1W') AND rank_no <= 3 THEN hist_rate
                when tenor in ('1M','3M') AND rank_no <= 5 THEN hist_rate
               when tenor in ('6M','1Y') AND rank_no <= 10 THEN hist_rate END) as Calculation
FROM (SELECT created_date, contributor,
       Tenor, hist_date, hist_rate,Seq_no,
       rank() over (partition by tenor order by seq_no DESC) as rank_no
      FROM TableName ) A
GROUP BY created_date,contributor, Tenor,hist_date,hist_rate;
```

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the GROUP BY and switch to a *Group Sum*

```
SELECT created_date, contributor, Tenor, hist_date, hist_rate,
   SUM(case when tenor in ('O/N','1W') AND rank_no <= 3 THEN hist_rate
            when tenor in ('1M','3M') AND rank_no <= 5 THEN hist_rate
            when tenor in ('6M','1Y') AND rank_no <= 10 THEN hist_rate END)
   OVER (partition by tenor) as Calculation
FROM (SELECT created_date, contributor,
       Tenor, hist_date, hist_rate,Seq_no,
       rank() over (partition by tenor order by seq_no DESC) as rank_no
      FROM TableName ) A
```